# use of capture attribute in html input tag

Tags: html, input, image-capture

I would like to have an input html tag to allow my user to upload a image file or a pdf file or to capture a photo (and not a video or audio file).
Is it possible to do such a thing ?
I tried several codes (including the following one), but none of them work as expected

```
<input type="file" accept="images/*, .pdf" capture>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the correct types here:
https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

You need these types:

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*, application/pdf">
```

However, people will still be able to upload video files. You need serverside validation to prevent people to upload wrong files.

Comment: ok sorry for the mistake on doc type. But my question is still available with <input type="file" accept="image/*, application/pdf" capture>. With this code my device show me a menu with items to get a file on file system, take a picture, or take a video. I would like to have only "take a photo" "upload a file" but not "take a video" items

Comment: You can't do this with one input field. You'll need JS to add these functionality. Upload a file/photo is already covered. I would strongly advise this to capture photos. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageCapture/takePhoto